# AWK - Replace between two csv files and print correctly

Tags: awk

I have 2 files:

`f1.csv`:

```
CL*VIN
AV*AZA
PS*LUG
```

`f2.csv`:

```
2100-12-31*1234A*Thomas*Frederuc*1931-02-20*6791237*6791238*test1*1*0*0*CL*Jame 12*13*a1*zz3*D*13*1234*Tex*F
2100-12-31*1235A*Jack*Borbin*1931-02-21*7791238*7791239*test2*1*0*0*PS*Willliams Hou*14*a2*zz4*A*13*1235*Barc*F
2100-12-31*1236A*Pierce*Matheus*1931-02-22*8791239*8791240*test3*1*1*1*AV*Magnum st*15*a3*zz5*A*13*1236*Euo*F
```

And I want this output:

```
2100-12-31*1234A*Thomas*Frederuc*1931-02-20*6791237*6791238*test1*1*0*0*VIN*Jame 12*13*a1*zz3*D*13*1234*Tex*F
2100-12-31*1235A*Jack*Borbin*1931-02-21*7791238*7791239*test2*1*0*0*LUG*Willliams Hou*14*a2*zz4*A*13*1235*Barc*F
2100-12-31*1236A*Pierce*Matheus*1931-02-22*8791239*8791240*test3*1*1*1*AZA*Magnum st*15*a3*zz5*A*13*1236*Euo*F
```

I have the following code:

```
awk  -F"*" 'FNR==NR{ A[$1]=$2;next} ($12 in A){$12=A[$12];print}' OFS='*' f1.csv f2.csv
```

But the output is:

```
*Jame 12*13*a1*zz3*D*13*1234*Tex*F931-02-20*6791237*6791238*test1*1*0*0*VIN
*Willliams Hou*14*a2*zz4*A*13*1235*Barc*F791238*7791239*test2*1*0*0*LUG
*Magnum st*15*a3*zz5*A*13*1236*Euo*F-02-22*8791239*8791240*test3*1*1*1*VIN
```

How can I obtain my desired output?

Comment: Does your first file have Windows-style CRLF line endings and you're running this on a system that uses LF line endings?

Comment: I use windows 10 with wsl2, using dos2unix solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine here, what's your system/code environment and `awk` version?

It seems something to do with carriage returns, so better run this before dealing with these files:

```
dos2unix files
```

However, you can try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="*";RS="\r\n|\r|\n";}FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2;next}($12 in A){$12=A[$12];print}' f1.csv f2.csv
```

Comment: I use  windows 10 with wsl2, your awk  code worked, thanks